# Validate Url as request parameter in Spring

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, url

I would like to validate Url coming as request parameter.

In my Controller I have:

`@RequestParam(value = "inputUrl") String inputUrl`

I would like to have kind of validation as annotation.

I've tried adding `@Validated` and `@URL` but with no luck.

Comment: we can create our own as well.

Comment: @ankidaemon ok, but how to make those to wok?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html

Comment: @ankidaemon My problem is not how to write a validator, but how to use this validator on request parameter